# jQuery on() not working in Chrome, Safari. Works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have a page where you click on a calendar day (e.g. Monday the 1st), and it ajax-loads in some class times in a div elsewhere on the page, wrapping each in a div with a class called timeSpan.  I then have the user click on one of those times (which highlights it) to pick one.  This works great in Firefox, but I discovered today that it doesn't work in Safari or Chrome.  Haven't tried IE because I'm on a Mac.  This is the code:

```
jQuery.root.on("click", ".timeSpan", function(event) {
```

I had had it as .delegate() instead of .on() and that worked fine too.  Then I searched here and found suggestions to use .on, so I switched.  Still works in FF, but not in anything else.  I'm using jQuery 2.1.4 but I can change if needed.

This is the line that renders the timeSpan divs:

```
html+= "<div class='timeSpan' data-classdate='" + class_date + class_date_endTime + "' data-date='" + class_date2 + "' data-eventid='" + eventid + "'>" + the_date + ",<br>" + start_time + " to " + end_time + "</div><br>";
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: not sure why you have used `jQuery.root`, maybe new jQuery 2.x.x has it.. I would check.. can you try `jQuery(document).on` instead..

Comment: What is `jQuery.root`?

Comment: Checked the new versions, didnt find `root` property, but found `rootjQuery` property which points to `document` but used internally. Quite surprising that its working in Firefox as you are saying.

Comment: Sorry... I should have included that line.  Very first line of my code inside the $(document).ready() is jQuery.root = $(this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are generating the html dynamically, you need to delegate the click event on the document.

```
html+= "<div class='timeSpan' data-classdate='" + class_date + class_date_endTime + "' data-date='" + class_date2 + "' data-eventid='" + eventid + "'>" + the_date + ",<br>" + start_time + " to " + end_time + "</div><br>";

$(document).on("click", ".timeSpan", function(event) { // delegates the click event on the dom and during event invocation checks class timespan 

});
```